# Empty String is not treated as null in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

My understanding of the following statement is that if blank or empty string is inserted into hive column, it will be treated as null.

```
TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format'=''
```

To test the functionality i have created a table and insertted '' to the filed 3. When i query for nulls on the field3, there are no rows with that criteria.

Is my understanding of making blank string to null correct??

```
CREATE TABLE CDR
(
field1                 string,
field2                 string,
field3                 string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
**TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format'='');**

insert overwrite table emmtest.cdr select **field1,field2,''** from emmtest.cdr_non_orc;

select * from emmtest.cdr where **field3 is null;**
```

The last statement has not returned any rows. But i am expecting all rows to be returned since there is blank string in field3.

Comment: An empty string never equals null.  `field3=''` will return those rows.

Comment: How do i make empty strings to null in Hive? What does this parameter mean? - TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format'='')

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format'='')` means the following:

- An empty field in the data files will be treated as NULL when you query the table
- When inserting rows to the table, NULL values will be written to the data files as empty fields

You are doing something else -
You are inserting an empty string to a table from a query.
It is treated "as is" - an empty string.

#### Demo

**bash**

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hive/warehouse/mytable
echo Hello,,World | hdfs dfs -put - /user/hive/warehouse/mytable/data.txt
```

**hive**

```
create table mytable (s1 string,s2 string,s3 string) 
row format delimited 
fields terminated by ','
;
```

---

```
hive> select * from mytable;
OK
s1  s2  s3
Hello       World
```

---

```
hive> alter table mytable set tblproperties ('serialization.null.format'='');
OK
```

---

```
hive> select * from mytable;
OK
s1  s2  s3
Hello   NULL    World
```

Comment: Thank you...How do i make empty strings to null in Hive?

Comment: Unlike Oracle, other database engines, including Hive, do not treat empty strings as NULL. You can However use `nullif(mycolumn,'')` (as of Hive 2.2.0) or `case when mycolumn <> '' then mycolumn end`

Comment: Thank you Dudu for clarifying my questions.

Comment: Does this property work on orc tables as well?i have a source table on which i ran "select * from source where gender is null" and it gives results. I have inserted the rows from source to target using above mentioned query as "insert into target select * from source where gender is null". But inserted rows in target comes with gender as '' and query "select * from target where gender is null' shows 0 count while 'select * from target where gender='' shows exact same count as source. Both source and target tables are ORC. Please clarify.

Comment: @rahulgulati, post a question with a reproducible scenario. In any case I doubt that `serialization.null.format` will have any effect on any file format other than textfile.

Comment: FYI, Some thing different in my situation. I use Hive 1.2.1 and spark 1.6, connect Hive with spark beeline, when I use `insert into mytable select * from (select 'Hello', '', 'World');`. I get the insert empty string as same behavior as `echo Hello,,World | hdfs dfs -put - /user/hive/warehouse/mytable/data.txt` did. Query as `NULL` and store as empty string

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following in your Hive Query properties:

```
NULL DEFINED AS ''
```

or any character inside the quotes.