# Replace empty string in hive- Nvl and COALESCE tried

Tags: sql, hive, null, hiveql

How to replace an empty string(length 0 ) with some other value?  Already used `Nvl` and `COALESCE` but both doesn't replace with the replacement value because the value is not null. i can use `case` statement but looking for a built in function if there is any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are having empty strings so when we use **coalesce or nvl** works only if we are having **null values** in the data. These functions **won't work with empty strings.**

**With Empty strings:**

```
hive> select coalesce(string(""),"1");
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
|      |
+------+--+
hive> select nvl(string(""),"1");
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
|      |
+------+--+
```

**With null values:**

```
hive> select coalesce(string(null),"1");
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 1    |
+------+--+
hive> select nvl(string(null),"1");
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 1    |
+------+--+
```

Try to **[alter the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43263038/empty-string-is-not-treated-as-null-in-hive)** and add this property

```
TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format'='')
```

if this property doesn't display empty string as null's then we need to use either `case/if` statement to replace empty strings.

You can use [`if statement`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions)

> **if(boolean testCondition, T valueTrue, T valueFalseOrNull)**

```
 hive> select if(length(trim(<col_name>))=0,'<replacement_val>',<col_name>) from <db>.<tb>;
```

**Example:**

```
 hive> select if(length(trim(string("")))=0,'1',string("col_name"));
    +------+--+
    | _c0  |
    +------+--+
    | 1    |
    +------+--+
hive> select if(length(trim(string("1")))=0,'1',string("col_name"));
    +-----------+--+
    |    _c0    |
    +-----------+--+
    | col_name  |
    +-----------+--+
```

Answer (score 1):

In Hive, empty string is treated like usual comparable value, not NULL. That is why there is no built-in function for this.

Using case statement:

```
case when col='' or col is null then 'something' else col end
```