# Preventing "NULL" values in Hive

Tags: hive

I have thousands of rows of this structure 
sum(case when sp_flag='Y' then 1 else 0 end) SP_Fl

How can I force the unknowns to be 0 instead of NULL and have the column be numeric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [coalesce (or) NVL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) functions to replace NULL values with 0.

```
hive> select coalesce(int(null),0); --replacing integer null value with 0
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 0    |
+------+--+
hive> select nvl(int(null),0); --replacing integer null value with 0
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 0    |
+------+--+
```

For more details regards to replace empty strings/Null values refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404789/replace-empty-string-in-hive-nvl-and-coalesce-tried/52406625#52406625) link.

> ***UPDATE:***

**1. Replacing NULL values in the strings:**

```
hive> select coalesce(string(NULL),0);
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 0    |
+------+--+
hive> select coalesce(string(NULL),0);
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 0    |
+------+--+
```

**2. Replacing "NULL" strings:**

We cannot replace NULL strings with **coalesce** because there is NULL string(length of 4) is in the data but coalesce only replaces null values.

```
hive> select coalesce(string("NULL"),0),length(string("NULL"));
+-------+------+--+
|  _c0  | _c1  |
+-------+------+--+
| NULL  | 4    |
+-------+------+--+
```

If you are having this kind of data then write a `case statement (or) regexp_replace (or) replace` functions to replace NULL strings with 0.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: If it is a string and I want to make it an integer, will this work?

Comment: The original column is a string format with many integer values and values of "NULL" for missing values. I'd like to change the "NULL" to 0 and convert the entire column to integer.

Comment: @Olivia, yes if you are having NULL values not **"NULL"** strings in the data then coalesce function works. Check my new edit **UPDATE** section of the answer for replacing strings using coalesce function.

Comment: Thanks! Mine were forced into strings because of the "NULL" value. I used nvl and cleaned the data before exporting. Then they came in as numeric. Thanks again!